# SQL Create Table Default value as specific date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, default, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle's APEX and trying to set the default date of one of my columns to '31-dec-2013', but for the life of me, it's not happening. I've tried many syntax variations and gotten a number of errors such as "not a valid month" and "such a unique or primary key exists" something to that effect. Please help! here's my code:

```
Create Table Lease(        
LeaseNo number(8) not null unique,
PropertyID number(6) not null,
ClientId varchar2(4) not null,
Leasestartdate date not null,
LeaseEndDate date dEFAULT ('31-12-2013'),
MonthlyRent number(8,2) check (MonthlyRent >1000),
Primary Key (LeaseNo),
Foreign key (propertyId) references property(Propertyid),
Foreign key (clientId) references client(clientid));
```

It threw the "not a valid month" error.

Comment: For questions related to Oracle Application Express (APEX) please use tag "oracle-apex", not "apex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_date` with an explicit date format model as ThorstenKettner shows, which means you won't be relying on the session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT. You can also use a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062), which is always in YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
...
LeaseEndDate date default date '2013-12-31',
...
```

Largely a matter of personal preference between the two though; I happen to prefer this, partly because it's slightly less typing, but also because there is no possibility of ambiguity between DD-MM and MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

Use TO_DATE to convert a string to date:

```
...
LeaseEndDate date default to_date('31-12-2013','dd-mm-yyyy')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 Corrections

1. First remove `UNIQUE` clause from `LeaseNo`, you cant make a cols primary key that has the unique Constraint already.
2. And, try this Format in default clause - '31-DEC-2013'

Comment: That format is also assuming the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to DD-MON-YYYY, which may not be the case. In fact it isn't, as the OP's implicit conversion would work with that.